# Access command line values during Snakemake pipeline run

Tags: python, command-line, snakemake

Is it possible to access the values of arguments that were parsed to `Snakemake` in the command line or set in the profile yaml file?

For example, I would like to know whether `--slurm` is `True` so that I can split certain jobs to allow for optimal parallelisation.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the parameters have corresponding environment variables. For example, if the pipeline was managed by slurm, a $SLURM_JOB_ID was set. Other slurm related environment variables or snakemake related variables could be referenced e.g. [here](https://docs.hpc.shef.ac.uk/en/latest/referenceinfo/scheduler/SLURM/SLURM-environment-variables.html#gsc.tab=0) and [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html).